# Weird behaviour on Javascript clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have came across this problem by answering another question. I have a working JavaScript clock with three lines containing the day, the current time, and the date. These lines should have the same width, so I used [BigText](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/) plugin for that which is working fine except one thing.

```js
tday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

function GetClock(){
    var d=new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
    var dx=d.toGMTString();
 dx=dx.substr(0,dx.length -3);
 d.setTime(Date.parse(dx))
 d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 0);
    var nday=d.getDay(),nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getYear(),nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds(),ap;

        if(nhour==0){ap=" AM";nhour=12;}
   else if(nhour<12){ap=" AM";}
   else if(nhour==12){ap=" PM";}
   else if(nhour>12){ap=" PM";nhour-=12;}

 if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
 if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
 if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

    document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = "" + tday[nday].toUpperCase() + "";
    document.getElementById('1').setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    
    document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = "" + nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec + "" + ap + "";
    document.getElementById('2').setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    
    document.getElementById('3').innerHTML = "" + tmonth[nmonth].toUpperCase() + " " + ndate + ", " + nyear + "";
    document.getElementById('3').setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
}

window.onload=function(){
    GetClock();
    setInterval(GetClock,1);
}
```

```css
body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial; }
#bigtext {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    color: #bcbcbc;
    padding: 40px 15px;
}
.bigtext-line1 {
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 260px;" id="bigtext">
    <div id="1" class="bigtext-line0"><br/></div>
    <div id="2" class="bigtext-line1"><br/></div>
    <div id="3" class="bigtext-line2"><br/></div>
</div>

<select id="font" style="display: none;">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
</select>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.zachleat.com/bigtext/demo/js/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.zachleat.com/bigtext/demo/js/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.zachleat.com/bigtext/bigtext.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.zachleat.com/bigtext/demo/bigtextWizard.js"></script>
```

There is a weird behaviour I couldn't figure out. You can see a padding on the right of the clock, which disappears, when you edit one of the lines on the clock. (`contenteditable = true`) However, I don't want users to edit the clock, so I want to use `contenteditable = false`, but if I use that, I cant get rid of the padding on the right.

### What I've tried so far

is setting `document.getElementById('1').focus()` and after that simulating a keypress with jQuerys trigger event (when I try to edit one of the lines, and push *any* button, the padding disappears):

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 20; //Caps Lock
$("whatever").trigger(press);
```

but sadly I could'nt get it done. I was also searching for solutions for hours, probably a fresh look will help me.

### What should it look like?

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: On Firefox it renders just fine. Just remove the `contenteditable` and try to debug and edit the CSS. It is most likely at fault here.

Comment: Hmmm... Disabling the `font-size` from `#bigtext` helps in Chrome but breaks on Firefox...

Comment: @Sevanteri if i remove the `contenteditable` from the code above, it gets a `contenteditable=true` from one of the resources. I dont want that. I tried IE, Firefox, and Chrome, but it only works on Firefox for me as well. Also BigText isn't recognised by IE.

Comment: It's the BigText wizard that enables it? Do you need the wizard there for the users?

Comment: @Sevanteri Actually I don't. But `bigtextWizard.js` is the engine of it.

Comment: I think the wizard is just for setting the text up. And after you're done you're supposed to copy the resulting CSS and just use that and ditch the wizard.

Comment: @Sevanteri The CSS that the wizard provides when you try something out is just two lines for me. Am I that dumb or I am missing something?

Comment: Actually, it seems that you're just using the plugin wrong. The wizard is only for the demo, I guess. You're supposed to call `$('#bigtext').bigtext();` in javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71856/discussion-between-balintpekker-and-sevanteri).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the BigText wizard, which seems to be meant for the BigText demo. Removing that javascript from the resources is part of the solution.

The second part is using the plugin the way it is meant to be used. As in call `$("#myBigTextElement").bigtext()` and that should be it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdgy4tfb/5/

Comment: Somehow the `setInterval(GetClock,1000);` missed out from `window.onload=function()` don't know why. Without this, the clock dosn't update itself. For feature readers' attention. Thanks for help!